# c++ template use without argument

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

There i s template class

```
template <class T>
class Dao { ... }
```

and
a couple of classes inherit from it. (BarDao and FooDao)

Then, there is another class called Server that must use either BarDao or FooDao figured out dynamically.

So,

```
class Server {
    Dao * dao;
    Server(Dao * dao) {this->dao = dao;}
}
```

I get a compilation error complaining about no arguments.
How could I avoid getting this error?

---

Addition.

The reason why I used the template was to accomplish the following:

1. I wanted to have an abstract class that has methods

   `T compute();`
2. BarDao has a method

   `SomeClass compute()`;
3. FooDao has a method

   `SomeOtherClass compute()`;

Is there better approach than using a template?

Sorry, if questions are dumb. I'm a c++ beginner.

Comment: `Dao` is not a class. `Dao` is a template. You can have a pointer to a class, but not to a template. No further answer is possible without an [mcve].

Comment: Types of expressions must be known at compile-time. You could define a non-template interface that `FooDao` and `BarDao` derive from.

Comment: @M.M I Initially started with non-template interface, but isn't it impossible to override a method with different return type? That was why I thought of using T in the interface.

Comment: If a function returns base reference, the derived overrider can return derived reference

Comment: @M.M would there be any other way?  SomeClass is not something I wrote.. I guess I could create a wrapper to have SomeClass in it, but that doesn't sound nice to me.

Comment: impossible to say based on the (lack of) detail you have provided

Comment: what would the return type of `dao->compute()` be ? Types of expressions must be known at compile-time

Comment: @M.M hmm Dao is an abstract class (more like interface that define what methods FooDao and BarDao must implement)..  does it still have to have a return type?

Comment: All functions must have a return type

Comment: Hmm yeah, I'm so lost in this one. I was hoping making the class as template and setting T the return type would solve it, but apparently not..

Comment: (Virtual) overrides can have *covariant return types* (see [virtual function specifier](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/virtual)). Although, without a [mcve], I doubt there is much we can do to help. So far it all looks like very broken design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Dao` is not a concrete class, it is a *class template*. `Dao* dao` doesn't refer to an incomplete type, it refers to a template. It needs to be qualified.

You state that you want it resolve automatically, so we just repeat what you're doing in Dao itself.

```
template<class T>
class Dao
{
    T t_;
public:
    Dao(T t) : t_(t) {}
};

template<class T>
class Server
{
    using dao_t = Dao<T>;

    dao_t* dao_;
public:
    Server(dao_t* dao) : dao_(dao) {}
};

int main() {
    Server<int> server(nullptr);

    return 0;
}
```

Demo: http://ideone.com/GNcjMm

Answer (score 1):

Dao in this case is a template not a class.  You might want to change your code in the example you gave us Dao :

```
Dao<int> dao;
```

Also another idea to point out. You can't have a pointer to a template,  but you can to a class. If you are desperate to use a pointer you might as well use a class. Hope this helped!

An alternative to this can be making a string like "int" and based on that you can make if/else method on which method to call. For one method you will have different return values (polymorphism) .  Sorry I would give you a code sample but I am answering you via a phone.  [Here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/polymorphism/) is a good article about polymorphism. Polymorphism is the ugly workaround I can think of now for templates. I might update answer later.  Hope this helped!

Comment: thanks for your reply.  Didn't know template is different from the class. Could you please take a look at added part in the question? Thanks!